# How to calculate convergence of this function?

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation

Given $n$, is there any easy way to calculate convergence of this summation.

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{1}{^{n+k}C_n}$$

EDIT: Also I need to find at which value this series converges.

Comment: You may be "given $n$" but I wouldn't say "Given $k$ and $n$", since $k$ doesn't stay fixed but runs through $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have

$${n+k\choose n}=\frac{(n+k)!}{n!k!}=\frac1{n!}(k+1)(k+2)\cdots(k+n)\sim_\infty\frac{k^n}{n!}$$
hence

$$\frac{1}{{n+k\choose n}}\sim_\infty\frac{n!}{k^n}$$
and the Riemann series

$$\sum_{k\ge1}\frac1{k^n}$$
is convergent if and only if $n>1$.

**Edit** The sum of this series by telescoping is:

$$n!\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{(k+1)(k+2)\cdots(k+n)}\\=\frac{n!}{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{(k+1)(k+2)\cdots(k+n-1)}-\frac1{(k+2)(k+3)\cdots(k+n)}\\=\frac{n!}{(n-1)\times (n-1)!}=\frac n{n-1}$$

Comment: I also need to find where it converges. Edited the question

Answer (score 3):

Using the recurrence for Pascal's Triangle, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{\binom{k-1}{n-1}}-\frac1{\binom{\vphantom{1}k}{n-1}}
&=\frac{\binom{k-1}{n-2}}{\binom{k-1}{n-1}\binom{\vphantom{1}k}{n-1}}\\[4pt]
&=\frac{\frac{n-1}{n}}{\binom{\vphantom{1}k}{n}}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Summing $(1)$ we get
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{\binom{k+n\vphantom{1}}{n}}
&=\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac1{\binom{k\vphantom{1}}{n}}\\
&=\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{k=n}^m\frac1{\binom{k\vphantom{1}}{n}}\\
&=\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{n}{n-1}\sum_{k=n}^m\left[\frac1{\binom{k-1}{n-1}}-\frac1{\binom{\vphantom{1}k}{n-1}}\right]\\
&=\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{n}{n-1}\left[1-\frac1{\binom{\vphantom{1}m}{n-1}}\right]\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
As long as $n\gt1$, the series converges to $\dfrac{n}{n-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the $k(\frac {a_k}{a_{k+1}}−1)=k(\frac {n+k+1}{k+1}−1)=\frac{kn}{k+1}→n$ If $k→∞$ so the series converges iff $n>1$[By, Raabe's Test. Also see that if $n=1$ then $a_k=\frac1k$ the series is divergent].

Comment: Ok. But why have you deleted my answer??

Comment: How dare you to edit my answer such a way !!!! Its my first experience thats why I approved it without looking it... In future I will take care of it.@Stupid you are really a stupid.

Comment: If a contest is going on then you have to take care of the security reason.

Comment: In future if such a thing happens then I will definitly take an action.

Comment: Don't blindly accept suggested edits.

Comment: @robjohn Yeah obviously in future I will take care of it. Actually this happens for first time with me. In previous cases all the edits are were very useful to me. So, I neglected it. It was my fault.I have given the solution at first,but stupid deleted it. But every answer of me is like a child to me.I have to write it very carefully.Here I had to repeat it again. Thats why I was tempered. Sorry to all.

Comment: If someone makes an edit you don't like, you can click on the message which says "edited xxx minutes ago" and pick the version you want to rollback to. No need to retype everything.

Comment: @robjohn Oh, Thank you very much.